# How to install gcc-9 on debian:latest docker

Tags: c++, docker, gcc, debian

In order to use the C++17 include `<filesystem>` I need `gcc-9` package in my debian docker.

By default [`debian:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian) (aka 10 or buster) will install gcc `8.3.0` from the regular distro repo.

Is there any PPA, testing repo, whatever, where I can **easily** install a `gcc-9` (or later) package (i.e. not build it from source)

Thanks !

note: need gcc-9 to have good C++17 `<filesystem>` support.
GCC 9 Release note:

> Using the types and functions in  does not require linking with -lstdc++fs now.

src: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html

note2: CMake 3.16* doesn't support any cxx_filesystem compiler feature AFAIK.

note3: you can found log here: https://github.com/Mizux/KalistoUnpacker/runs/642516660?check_suite_focus=true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my Dockerfile I did:

```
FROM debian:latest AS env
...
RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y gcc
```

note: I added these line after the install of `build-essential` so technically the container install the "default" gcc then it is updated by the one in the testing repo...

note2: Using `RUN gcc --version` I've got `gcc (Debian 9.3.0-11) 9.3.0` :D

Comment: I would like to do this as well, but I don't know what a dockerfile is and where to find it. Could you explain that?

Comment: @C.Binair Dockerfile is the format use to "describe" your container image recipe
ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: I had to use `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y gcc` to be able to skip the prompt from gcc

Answer (score 9):

From a fresh start of `debian:10`:

```
echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list
apt update
cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 650
EOF

apt install -qq -y -t testing build-essential
```

yields:

```
# g++ -v
gcc version 9.3.0 (Debian 9.3.0-11)
```

Comment: If the downvote was because my answer breaks one of the pinning rules or something else, I would love to be educated.

Comment: Me too, I want to know why someone down vote this !

Comment: @Botje Does this procedure upgrade from Buster to Bullseye? I did an `apt upgrade` after applying your changes, and from the amount of upgraded packages this really looks like I'm on Bullseye now... the kernel was updated to 5.x too.  BTW: Now you get GCC 10.2.0 from testing, it seems they moved from 9.3.0.

Comment: @Botje It seems I upgraded all packages before creating the pin file, so I actually upgraded to Bullseye... I'm fine with Bullseye, but now the problem is that whenever I want to install something, I need to do a `apt install -t testing` or otherwise it will refuse to install... how can I avoid the need for the `-t testing` now?